# trigger keyup at primefaces column filter oncomplete

Tags: primefaces

I would like to trigger keyup on primefaces column filter at oncomplete so that datatable can re-filter. I tried the below. But it doesn't seem to have effect?

```
oncomplete="$('#form1\\:mm1001_datatable_listOfMoneyMarket\\:mm1001_column_tradeid').trigger('filter')"
oncomplete="$('#form1\\:mm1001_datatable_listOfMoneyMarket\\:mm1001_column_tradeid').trigger('keyup')"

    <h:form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false">
        <p:dataTable
            styleClass="dataTable" id="mm1001_datatable_listOfMoneyMarket"
            value="#{pc_Mm1001.w_mmdeal.theListingOfMoneyMarket}"
            var="varlistOfMoneyMarket" rows="50" paginator="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}
            {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="10, 25, 50, 75,100,200"
            resizableColumns="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            filteredValue="#{pc_Mm1001.w_mmdeal.listOfFilteredMoneyMarket}" 
            widgetVar="listOfMoneyMarket">

            <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{pc_Mm1001.filterListener}"></p:ajax>

            <p:column id="mm1001_column_tradeid" width="90"
                sortBy="#{varlistOfMoneyMarket.trade_id}"
                filterBy="#{varlistOfMoneyMarket.trade_id}"
                filterMatchMode="contains" resizable="true"
                rendered="#{pc_Mm1001.showColumn_trade_id}"
                filterStyle="width:80px"
                style="text-align: left; font-weight : 400"
                headerText="#{msg.mm1001_gridheader_trade_id}" 
                filterValue="#{pc_Mm1001.w_mmdeal.fv_trade_id}">

                <p:commandLink ajax="false" styleClass="commandLink"
                    id="mm1001_commandlink_tradeid" 
                    action="#{pc_Mm1001.doMm1001_commandlink_tradeidAction}">
                    <h:outputText id="mm1001_gridoutput_tradeid"
                        styleClass="outputGridText_px"
                        value="#{varlistOfMoneyMarket.trade_id}"></h:outputText>
                    <f:param name="clicked_transaction_id"
                        value="#{varlistOfMoneyMarket.transaction_id}"></f:param>
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>

    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ids seems to be wrong because pf filters have `:filter` suffix, (to find out the filter `input` id do (in chrome): right click on the filter input -> Inspect element

take a look at the showcase: [DataTable - Filtering](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf)

to filter the model column in the showcase the following code will work:

set some value (for example 7)

```
$('#form\\:dataTable\\:modelColumn\\:filter').val('7');
```

trigger the keyup event on the filter input

```
$('#form\\:dataTable\\:modelColumn\\:filter').keyup();
```

Comment: can it be executed using RequestContext when the page load?

Comment: I guess you can use something like this:    `<f:metadata><f:event listener="#{myBean.myMethod}" type="preRenderView" /></f:metadata>` and inside `myMethod` use the `RequestContext` to execute your js